# Could life survive on a diet of dust?

Tags: biology, internal-consistency, fauna

Could life survive on a diet of dust or some other substance that is both abundant and that we don't place any value on?

Comment: Before reading the rest of the question, I thought this was going to be a question about living on a mote of dust like a tiny planet, rather than consuming dust...

Comment: This is an interesting question, but also very easily solved by a [search online](https://www.google.com/search?q=does+anything+eat+dust). I've opened a [meta discussion](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/459/question-that-can-be-easily-answered-with-a-quick-search-online) about whether this should be on topic.

Comment: I think this question would be more interesting if we excluded organic dust.

Comment: Downvoting as per [SE policy](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/443/questions-that-show-a-lack-of-basic-research).
I might ask a variant of this question once I get the framing right.

Comment: Upvoting because I liked the question and because there is no exact answer, meaning it's a possibility to learn. We must be careful with locking or downvoting open questions on a Q&A forum which is based on concepts. There are no straight answers for concepts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [house dust mite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_dust_mite) already does that.

> Dust mites feed on organic detritus such as flakes of shed human skin and flourish in the stable environment of dwellings.

Comment: it should be noted though, that without humans, the dust mite would likely not survive

Comment: It is noted. "shed *human* skin"

Answer (score 7):

Mourdos' answer mentions dust mites, which feed off organic matter in dust.

Another possible answer is [lithophilic bacteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithophile), which literally survive by eating rocks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but for different reasons.

#### Mineral Dust

If the dust is from rocks, then a life-form could probably survive mainly because of the minerals. For example, a plant could survive off the mineral-rich dust eroded from rocks.

#### Organic Dust

This is the usual household dust, and as has been mentioned, dust mites do feed on this, so life on organic dust is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you made it a plant, (of sorts,) it could use photosynthesis + minerals, specifically carbon, oxygen, etc. to live on dust. And the photosynthesis would be the source of energy, as you sort of need that.

Comment: This is probably how life(photosynthetic micro organisms) survived/restarted following the asteroid theory of dinosaur extinction.